Mocking snowflake VARIANT type in pytest
In the team we are using Snowflake as a relational database. We one field has VARIANT type. As ORM I am using SQLAlchemy along with snowflake-sqlalchemy. I defined the following model:
class Table1(Base):
    __tablename__ = config.model_metadata_table_name

    id: int = Column(Integer, Sequence(config.model_metadata_id_sequence_name), primary_key=True)
    details: str = Column(VARIANT)

I wanted to write a few unit tests which use in memory sqllite database instead of snowflake. The problem is that sqllite has no VARIANT type and it fails when it wants to create tables in database. I wanted to mock VARIANT type (from snowflake-sqlalchemy) with String type (from sqlalchemy). The problem is that I don't know how to do it properly. Pytest fixtures are applied in execution phase but Base object is built in import phase.
Any ideas how to do it or how to use sqllite for snowflake testing in a different way?

you can do Column(VARIANT().with_variant(String, 'sqlite')), its not a mock, but IMO this seems like a better way to approach this than mock
